# Failed to update bundle: x.jar with ID y. The bundle has been uninstalled

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

In Liferay 7, I have put a module JAR into `deploy/`, then I uninstalled it via Gogo Shell, and now I want to install it again.

PROBLEM: When I copy it again into `deploy/` I get this error:

```
INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:252] Processing httpclient-osgi-4.5.3.jar
WARN  [fileinstall-/home/nico/liferay/osgi/modules][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:103] Failed to update bundle: /home/nico/liferay/osgi/modules/httpclient-osgi-4.5.3.jar with ID 1088. The bundle has been uninstalled
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you deploy something via Liferay's `deploy` folder, it gets introduced into the OSGi runtime through a mechanism called FileInstall.

When you undeploy from the running system through Gogo shell, the component gets uninstalled, but the directory which is backing FileInstall still contains the bundle (meaning that it would be reinstalled on next deployment). Typically this is not what you want.

Rule of thumb: When you deploy through FileInstall, undeploy through FileInstall. When you deploy through Gogo Shell, undeploy through Gogo Shell. Do not mix both. Decide for one.

As Liferay is only using FileInstall, it's safe not to use Gogo Shell for productive deployments. Plus: Bundles installed through Gogo Shell won't end up in the directory that backs FileInstall. The bundle might not be there after redeployment (especially when you delete the `osgi/state` folder, which is sometimes asked for.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the JAR file in your Liferay's `osgi/modules/` folder and delete it.

Second, copy the JAR again to `deploy/` again.

References:

- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-72283
- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-67254

Answer (score 0):

delete the .war file from your `\osgi\war` folder and deploy(copy from `\build\libs` to `\deploy` folder)  again. it will work.